# How to show a placeholder image in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, html5-canvas

Using AngularJS, and in a particular view we are using the natural size of the image to drive the layout (using max-heights, max-widths, but letting the image expand as much as possible to fit within that area).

We also use a placeholder data-uri for the image based on pre-determined height and width for the image as well as dominant color information.  The reason we do this is because using a canvas image gives us the same 'natural' sizing info and we don't have to constantly re-calculate widths and heights for a div for resizes while maintaining aspect ratios, etc.

So, the directive first creates a data-uri using Canvas and sets it as the value of `scope.imgSrc`, then after a slight delay (just a `$timeout(0)`) we update that scope value with the actual image source url.

Unfortunately, this doesn't always work.  Often, the template doesn't actually render until after we've already updated the scope value to point to the real URL.  The result is that the data-uri never gets rendered to the screen, and we end up only displaying the real url.  On a slow network, this means a blank area where the placeholder should be, because the placeholder never renders.

Is there anyway to guarantee that something renders at least once before I switch the value?

Comment: Has increasing the timeout helped? What happens if you just set a 1000 timeout? I'm assuming you're using correctly. 0 timeout is super fast, and depends on the performance of the browser. You might have to look into image prefetch or preloading then apply the url once the image is loaded and show the placeholder until then.

Comment: Exactly, its timed out before the image is rendered from the  url, you need to increase the timeout to render the image, till then you can use a static image and it will switch after image is rendered **OR** Let the Spinner do its job till the image renders.

Comment: $timeout is supposed to run_after_ the current digest loop, optionally creating a new one, so the timeout value of 0 was just a means to get a new digest loop.  My assumption was that after any given digest loop the browser would be allowed to render.  I don't want to use a longer timeout because it adds an arbitrary delay that would be felt in certain scenarios.  It may be that that's my only choice, I just don't like adding additional timeout in the hopes of something working.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I ended up going with was a custom onload directive for the image that removes the dataURI value, combined with the img tag itself using either the dataURI or the img source.

In the template:

```
<img ng-src="{{dataURI || imageSource}}" custom-onload="removeDataURI()">
```

In the directive:

```
scope.dataURI = getTheCanvasBasedURI();
scope.imageSource = getTheRealImageURL(); // this is async.

scope.removeDataURI = function() {
  scope.dataURI = undefined;
}
```

Comment: If `getTheRealImageURL` is async, then `cope.imageSource = getTheRealImageURL();` wouldn't work :)

Comment: You'd do something on the lines of `getTheRealImageURL().then( url => { scope.imageSource = url; })`

Comment: Yeah... it was meant to be informative.  I know how promises work.